# Capture which video id the user played from video array

Tags: javascript, html

This code works great on a page with only 1 video. I am trying to adapt it to work on a page with an array of videos (8 per page) All i need is to capture the video id which is stored in $item.vid when the player clicks play button.

I have tried adding a div with the video id value and all the divs on the page which are created by the look do in fact have different values which is great, however they all have the same div id.  So that does not help me.

```
<div id="output"></div>

 //foreach starts here

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

  //foreach ends here



<script>
    var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');

    // Playing event
    media.addEventListener("playing", function() {
        $("#output").html("Playing event triggered");
    });

    // Pause event
    media.addEventListener("pause", function() { 
        $("#output").html("Pause event triggered"); 
    });

    // Seeking event
    media.addEventListener("seeking", function() { 
        $("#output").html("Seeking event triggered"); 
    });

    // Volume changed event
    media.addEventListener("volumechange", function(e) { 
        $("#output").html("Volumechange event triggered"); 
    });

</script>
```

Expected results should be that when user clicks play js can grab that video record id from the page of multiple videos.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this was to think "keep it simple" and once i thought about that then the answer came.

Solution is to individualize each video tag in the array and i did this by adding the onclick option to the video tag (i was not aware this was possible till now).  Then inside that onclick you call a function and pass it the video id via the onclick event.

Something like this (i am working with smarty so vars go inside of {} brackets )

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" height="{$item.height}"  width="{$item.width}" poster="{$item.vbigthumb}" data-setup="{}" onclick="getVidId({$item.vid});">
          <source src="{$item.urlvid}" type="{$item.vtype}">   
          <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

And then the getVidId function grabs the video id passed to it via the onclick and then you can do whatever you want with the id at that point.   :)